# Having problems verifying profiles on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, verify

So I open an app and it says:

> "Untrusted Enterprise Developer."

So I go to the **Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management > the enterprise developer's name**. I tap "Verify App" and this comes up:

> Verifying will use your network connection to see if the app from this enterprise developer can be used on your iPad.

I tap "Verify" and nothing happens. I open the app and it still says "Untrusted Enterprise Developer."

Comment: Can you give more information please? Where are you installing this app from, what app is this. Are you developing this app for Enterprise?

Comment: Create certificates and provisioning profile again, then make the enterprise ipa file. I also got the same issue few days back, but in my case someone has revoked the certificate. So let you try once with new certificate and profile.

Comment: Is you iPad connected via Wifi? If so, try mobile internet, this worked for me.

Comment: I installed the app from iosem.us and the app is gba4ios. I dont have mobile internet.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem，and solved it with restart my device. You must ensure that the good network. You could try it, maybe it helps to you, too.